# Getting rid of two elements in an array at the same time

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I'm designing a game in JavaScript, and I'm having some trouble with the way things are removed relating to my collision detection function. 
It's Asteroids, so some of the objects are named accordingly.

My collision detection function is designed to check if there are collisions between the player and an asteroid, or a bullet and an asteroid. In the case of a bullet and an asteroid, one would expect both the bullet and the asteroid to disappear.

However, given how I'm checking for collisions, removing both the bullet and the asteroid it's collided with seems to be a challenge. Here is my relevant code:

```
for (var i=0;i<$_.mapObjs.length;i++) { //get one object to check
    var superBox = $_.mapObjs[i].hitBox; //get it's properties
    var objectName = $_.mapObjs[i].name;
    var isAsteroid =(objectName.indexOf("asteroid") == -1)?false:true; //is the object an asteroid?
    for (var y=0;y<$_.mapObjs.length;y++) { //get the object to check it against
        if (objectName !== $_.mapObjs[y].name) { //if we are not checking the object against its self
            var subName = $_.mapObjs[y].name;
            var subIsAsteroid = (subName.indexOf("asteroid") == -1)?false:true; //is the second object an asteroid?
            if (!(isAsteroid) || !(subIsAsteroid)) { //if we are not checking two asteroids against each other
                var subBox = $_.mapObjs[y].hitBox;
                var collision = rectIntersectsRect(superBox,subBox); //check for a collision using rectIntersectsRect
                if (collision) { //if there is a collision
                    if ((objectName == "player" && subIsAsteroid) || (isAsteroid && subName == "player")) { //if either of the objects are the player, then the player dies
                        if (!player.invincible)
                            player.death(); 
                    } else if ((objectName == "blankObject" && subIsAsteroid) || (isAsteroid && subName == "blankObject")) { //if either of the objects are a bullet, then we destroy the asteroid
                        Console.log(i + "," + y); //this is the problem area
                        Console.log("getting rid of " + objects[i].name + " and " + objects[y].name);
                        if (subIsAsteroid) { //splice the asteroid out of the second array
                            objects.splice(y,1);
                        } else { //splice the asteroid out of the first array
                            objects.splice(i,1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, because I need both the asteroid and bullet to dissapear when they collide, I change

```
if (subIsAsteroid) {
    objects.splice(y,1);
} else {
    objects.splice(i,1);
}
```

to

```
objects.splice(y,1);
objects.splice(i,1);
```

but then, whenever there is a collision, the function randomly deletes two objects off the array, even though the positions of both `y` and `i` refer to the bullet and asteroid objects. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Well first of all, what do you think happens to your index `i` when objects has one less element in it from your `objects.splice(y, 1)` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.splice()` doesn't just remove random elements, but after the `.splice(y,1)` operation removes one element the indexes of all the elements after `y` will be one less than before - all of these later elements "move up". So if `i` is greater than `y` it will no longer refer to the element you want it to.

If you remove whichever element has a higher index first it should be fine:

```
objects.splice(Math.max(y,i), 1);
objects.splice(Math.min(y,i), 1);
```

Having said that, I can't tell from your code what the relationship between `$_.mapObjs` and `objects` is but I think it might cause problems. You have nested loops iterating over `$_.mapObjs` with `y` and `i` as loop indexes, but then you remove elements from `objects` based on the `y` and `i` indexes from `$_.mapObjs`. Do these two arrays have the same elements in the same order? **This could explain your "random" element removal.** Should you be splicing out of `$_.mapObjs`? If so, you'd need to adjust `y` and `i` after the removal so that you don't skip elements on the next loop iteration.

Comment: `$_.mapObjs` and `objects` both serve a purpose, but they stay exactly the same all the time, as in every time the collisions function is called, `$_.mapObjs` is set to `objects`, this is because `$_.mapObjs` is part of my "engine", which accepts "game files", and `objects` is part of that game file.

Comment: OK, sounds like both variables reference the same underlying array, in which case why use both within that function? You will need to adjust both loop index variables after the splice operations.

Comment: It's useless to try and cut them out of `$_.mapObjs`, because `$_.mapObjs` is always the same as `objects`. I'm just trying to create some code that is reusable. That is why they are always the same.

Comment: If you want reusable code, don't use the `objects` variable within your function, _only_ use `$_.mapObjs`. (Or use both, I don't care: it's _your_ code.) But my point about how splicing elements out will change the indexes of other elements is the most likely reason why your code doesn't do what you want. You may also need a `continue` statement with a label to jump to the next iteration of the _outer_ loop after splicing, otherwise the inner loop will keep going trying to compare to the item from the outer that was just removed.

Comment: I switched to using `$_.mapObjs` and used `$_.mapObjs.splice(Math.max(i,y),1);`, etc. It was also a problem with how my bullets were being destroyed, they were on a timer and would always throw out an element on the array, so i made sure that the timer was canceled once there was a collision. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because when you splice the first index, your array changes. This means that the second index may or may not be correct; because the indices of the elements have changed. I'd recommend you to do something like this:

```
objects[y] = null;
objects[i] = null;

while( (remIndex = objects.indexOf(null)) !== -1 ){
    objects.splice(remIndex, 1);
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/daSyq/1)